# Approve self-answer quicker

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

Right now if I ask a question, and later on that day or the next I find a solution, and no other answers were posted or solved that question, I will post my own answer if it's the solver.

What I don't get is why I have to wait 2 days to approve it? It just makes me forget about the question and I won't always get back to it later; lowering my acceptance rate and leaving an unanswered question in attention.

I see it as no different than asking a question and marking "answer my own question" at the bottom, actively answering it immediately.

I think there should be no delay to approving own answers, or make it significantly smaller than 2 days.

Comment: *Self answers are a disincentive to other users who may otherwise be willing to post more accurate, detailed material stemming from broader or deeper knowledge and/or experience than the asker has.*

Comment: You shouldn't give up on/"forget about" a question after just 2 days, and you should make the effort to go back to it.

Comment: @hayd maybe so, but you can't expect everyone to be that way. I personally will most likely get back to it, but would everyone?

Comment: no they won't, but they should and that behaviour should be encouraged.

Comment: I don't see any reminder from anyone for me to accept old answers

Answer (score 7):

An immediate accept would lead to it being less likely for other answers being posted. Why answer something that is answered after all. There is less of an incentive to do so.

Give others a chance as well. Posting your answer will bump the question, bringing it to the attention of the community once again.

Especially seeing the answer posted by the OP might lead to a better understanding of what was asked in the first place. If the lack of answers was caused by an unclear question, that answer might well lead to extra input.

So who knows what other great contributions might come in. Perhaps even better than yours.

P.s. there is no real need to worry about your accept rate (which is no longer visible). If you tend to accept answers when one can be accepted, that's just fine.

Comment: You're right about the acceptance rate, it's just something that has been embedded in me as a user - I hate to leave my questions unanswered. I always either get a solution from someone or solve it myself. And while it may be true that more contribution might come, that is why I also mentioned it can be significantly lowered and not necessarily removed altogether - maybe 1 day, 18 hours? after that long most questions would be invisible to most anyway, and it's more likely that people wouldn't mark it at all after 2 days have passed, because it would have been forgotten by then.

Comment: @Chen why is that a problem though? Most users will go through your questions eventually and accept those answers they forgot. With the accept rate gone, there is no real pressing reason to quickly accept stuff any more.

Comment: What is the problem there though? What harm does it cause when after (let's say) a month you think "Ha, I completely forgot to accept my own answer".

Comment: People posting other questions that might be related, are likely to get that question pop up when editing their title - see it's not answered, and most would not bother to look at it, resulting in a duplicate question.

Comment: Meh, that's taking this into a whole realm of assumptions that might not be based on facts.

Comment: There's more psychology involved in this issue than measurable facts.

Comment: You're now essentially asking for a change based on "I might forget to accept my answer, which might cause a user with the same question to not read mine, which might cause him to ask a duplicate" ... That's an awful lot of could/might/perhaps/possibly. Forgive me for saying so, but I think that's just an explanation you've come up with after the fact to substantiate your idea that you just want to accept your own answer immediately. It's not an actual problem that needs solving I think.